# PHP Filtering strings

Tags: php, filter, filtering

Im trying to remove some `'<p>'` tags from a string returned by wordpress. I've had a look at the php documentation but I can't seem to find a function that will alow me to define a string and then strip that string from a variable. Im new to php and I realize this must be a pretty simple operation. Any suggestions?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Please clarify whether you just want to remove the P tags or also the contents of the P elements. In addition, clarify if the P elements can occur with any attributes. Also point out whether your real goal is to remove all or just some elements, e.g. does your content only contain p elements but you really want to remove any elements or do you want to selectively remove elements, e.g. remove p elements but keep others.

Comment: I just would like to remove the <p> tags.

Comment: so there is other elements in the markup? You want to remove the P tags, keep the content and also keep any other elements and their content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use str_replace http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: +1: Although `strip_tags()` is probably what Thomas needs, still `str_replace()` is what Thomas asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
strip_tags($mystring); // this will remove all tags
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$myString = "<p>whatever you want in your string</p>";
$newString = str_replace(["<p>","</p>"], "", $myString);
echo $newString;
```

**Explanation**

Using `str_replace`, you can replace one or more strings with one or more other strings. In this case, we're replacing any `<p>` and `</p>` tags with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

[`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for either of `str_replace()` or (more likely, since you only want to replace *some* of them) `preg_match()`.